# Connect to mysql server on vps

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, vps

I want to connect to a MySQL server via MySQL workbench. So I edited `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` and set `bind-address = 0.0.0.0`. Also, I made sure that `skip-networking` is in none of the cnf-files. In ufw I `allowed mysql/tcp` Am I missing anything? Every time I test the connection I get the error `Host 'Ip.of.workbench-running.devices' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL-Server`.

Comment: You have checked if your vps were accepting connection from remote host in mysql/tcp port. Of course after change bind-address you restarted mysql server?

Comment: Yeah of cause I did `sudo service mysql restart`